# What would be the most suitable umbrella word for adding to a list and removing from a list?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a list of invitees,from which I can remove and add members. What am I doing to the list? I thought about editing, altering and so on, but that could potentially be confusing, as in editing the members in the invitee list.
My own strongest argument is for assemble, since the other members are added from the global members list. The list can also preexist and then could be edited.

My own thoughts are assemble, update, edit, is there a better word?

Comment: *Update* takes care of your issue. I'll try and look anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I am also currently using update, the fact that the list often already exists and is changed makes assemble a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **customize**d the list of guests to match the num7of seats.

See **customize** at [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/customize)

> Modify (something) to suit a particular individual or task.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/customize) defines **customize** as

> to build, fit, or alter according to individual specifications.